# fix header offsetting an html anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to clean up the way my anchors work. I have a header that is fixed to the top of the page, so when you link to an anchor elsewhere in the page, the page jumps so the anchor is at the top of the page, leaving the content behind the fixed header.

My below code is working as i want it to work. The only is issue i am getting with IE8. When I click on a jump link, it jump past it rather than to the correct position.

Can i get any help to fix this in ie8?

```
<script>
    ! function(o, n) {
      var t = function() {
        var n = o(":target"),
          t = 100;
        n.length > 0 && o("html, body").stop().animate({
          scrollTop: n.offset().top - t
        }, 80)
      };
      o(n).on("hashchange load", function() {
        t()
      })
    }(jQuery, window);
</script>
```

Comment: `The only is issue i am getting with IE8. Can i get any help to fix this in ie8?` - sure ... all you have to do is describe the "issue", otherwise how can anyone help?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used to fix this with css:

```
#anchor {
    position: relative;
}
#anchor:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 1px;
    top: -80px;
    left: 0;
}
```

80px is the top offset.